# A question about Uniqueness of Measure Theorem between two versions...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

When I study measure theory, I find that the Uniqueness of Measure Theorem seems having two versions. In probability theory book, the theorem was written as following:

*Let $P$ and $Q$ be probability measures on the measurable space $(\Omega, \sigma(\mathcal{E}))$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is a collection of sets closed under pairwise intersections (i.e. $\forall G,H\in\mathcal{E}: G\cap H\in\mathcal{E}$). If $P(A)=Q(A)$ for every $A\in \mathcal{E}$, then $P=Q$.*

*Fristedt, Bert; Gray, Lawrence*, A modern approach to probability theory, Boston: Birkhäuser (ISBN 0-8176-3807-5)).

There is another version (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniqueness_of_Measures). It has one more condition than above, which is "*there exists an exhausting sequence $⟨G_n⟩_{n∈\mathbb{N}}↑X$ in $G$*". This appended condition is really used in the proof.

Now I am confusing that why the "probability" version ignored this condition? Thanks for answering my question.

P.S. **exhausting sequence** is defined as https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Exhausting_Sequence_of_Sets.

Comment: Are you sure there's no extra conditions in the first version? For instance consider $\mathcal{E}$ to be all (measurable) subsets of a given proper subset $A\subset \Omega$. Then you can easily build examples where $P=Q$ on $\mathcal{E}$, but they're not the same measure.

Comment: I am pretty sure. I copied it word by word from the book cited in the main post.

Comment: Ok, I think there's a "sloppy" error on the first statement. The conclusion $P=Q$ should read: $P$ and $Q$ agree *on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}$*. Otherwise, examples like the one I gave arise.

Comment: Onto your question, notice that the Wiki page you cite has an extra condition (and this is what's really important): $\mu(G_n)$ is finite (in your case $\mu=P$). In the probability setting we can just take $G_n=\Omega$ for all $n$ (notice that we can always add $\Omega$ to $\mathcal{E}$).